# No query registered for [match]

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm working through some examples in the ElasticSearch Server book and trying to write a simple match query

```
{ 
  "query" : { 
    "match" : {
        "displayname" : "john smith"
    }
  }
}
```

This gives me the error:

```
{\"error\":\"SearchPhaseExecutionException[Failed to execute phase [query],      
....
SearchParseException[[scripts][4]: from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source 
....
QueryParsingException[[kb.cgi] No query registered for [match]]; }
```

I also tried

```
{ 
    "match" : {
    "displayname" : "john smith"
    }
}
```

as per examples on http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/match-query/

EDIT: I think the remote server I'm using is not the latest 0.20.5 version because using "text" instead of "match" seems to allow the query to work

I've seen a similar issue reported here: http://elasticsearch-users.115913.n3.nabble.com/Character-escaping-td4025802.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears the remote server I'm using is not the latest 0.20.5 version of ElasticSearch, consequently the "match" query is not supported - instead it is "text", which works

I came to this conclusion after seeing a similar issue reported here: http://elasticsearch-users.115913.n3.nabble.com/Character-escaping-td4025802.html

Answer (score 0):

Your first query looks fine, but perhaps the way you use in the request is not correct. Here is a complete example that works:

```
curl -XDELETE localhost:9200/test-idx
curl -XPUT localhost:9200/test-idx -d '{
    "settings": {
        "index": {
            "number_of_shards": 1,
            "number_of_replicas": 0
        }
    },
    "mappings": {
        "doc": {
            "properties": {
                "name": {
                    "type": "string", "index": "analyzed"
                 }
            }
        }
    }
}
'
curl -XPUT localhost:9200/test-idx/doc/1 -d '{
    "name": "John Smith"
}'
curl -XPOST localhost:9200/test-idx/_refresh
echo
curl "localhost:9200/test-idx/_search?pretty=true" -d '{
    "query": {
        "match" : {
            "name" : "john smith"
        }
    }
}
'
echo
```

Comment: Actually my bad, I just realized my local instance is running 0.20.5, and your query and my original query both work. It's against a remote server ..I think it must be using an older version since changing "match" to "text" fixed it and I saw a similar issue reported here: http://elasticsearch-users.115913.n3.nabble.com/Character-escaping-td4025802.html